# order words beside each other

Tags: text-formatting

how can I re order words beside each other in two columns?
for example:

```
 Mark 150 John 221 James 134 Sara 9873
```

I want it to be:

```
Mark 150
John 221
James 134
Sara 9873
```

Comment: Are the words in a file?

Comment: yes these are in a text file and generated by another script horizontally

Answer (score 10):

Do it this way:

```
echo 'Mark 150 John 221 James 134 Sara 9873' | xargs -n2
```

or

```
cat file | xargs -n2

Mark 150
John 221
James 134
Sara 9873

-n max-args, --max-args=max-args
          Use at most max-args arguments per command line.
```

Comment: Wow! very easy, I didn't think about this `xargs` functionality! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Or this way:

```
$ a='Mark 150 John 221 James 134 Sara 9873 '


$ printf '%s\n' $a  | paste - -


Mark    150
John    221
James   134
Sara    9873
```